# > Build error occurred Error: Cannot find module 'next-pwa/cache'

Tags: npm, next.js, package.json, yarn-v2

I have some problem with my next.js application.

When I use any yarn/npm/next command I'm getting similar error:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Cannot find module 'next-pwa/cache'
Require stack:
- D:\Criptic\next.config.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at mod._resolveFilename (C:\Users\carbo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:23:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:872:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Criptic\next.config.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\Criptic\\next.config.js' ]
}
```

This is my `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf \"{node_modules,.next,out.cache}\"",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.8",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "ethers": "^5.7.1",
    "framer-motion": "^7.3.6",
    "jotai": "^1.8.4",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "little-state-machine": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "next-seo": "^5.5.0",
    "next-sitemap": "^3.1.22",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "overlayscrollbars": "^1.13.1",
    "overlayscrollbars-react": "^0.3.0",
    "rc-slider": "^10.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.2",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.36.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-use": "^17.3.2",
    "recharts": "2.1.12",
    "swiper": "^8.4.2",
    "tiny-invariant": "^1.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web3modal": "^1.9.9",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
```

next-pwa is here.

This is my `next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache');
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  dest: 'public',
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  runtimeCaching,
});

const nextConfig = withPWA({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && {
    typescript: {
      ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
    eslint: {
      ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
  }),
});
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

If it possible please help me. Thank you in advance for your help

I tried to find something in the documentation about this, however, the only thing that I found approximately correct is the following link, which does not have an exact solution to this problem https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error

Comment: That version does not expose `next-pwa/cache`. If you want to use the default cache you don't have to pass anything to `runtimeCaching`. Simply have `const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({ dest: 'public', disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' });`.